# Преобразования чисел в строки не меняя тип других элементов в списке

Tags: python, map, lambda, int, строки

Есть такой список , нужно преобразовать числа в строки используя функцию map и lambda

```py
values = [21, 3, '43', 'pass', 'begin', 55, True, None] 
values = ['21', '3', '43', 'pass', 'begin', '55', True, None]
```

должен выйти второй вариант не меняя тип остальных значений , только цифры

Comment: нужно так нужно. Преобразовывайте

Comment: так у вас в списке уже строки, а не числа - что преобразовывать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

вам понадобятся:

- конструкция вида:

  ```
  map(lambda x: функция_от_x, arr)
  ```

`функция_от_х` должна определять тип `x`, если он числовой (а это или целочисленные - `int` или с плавающей запятой - `float`, преобразовывать в строку иначе возвращать как есть)

- функция для определения типа `type()`
- функция преобразования в строку `str()`
- преобразование в список через `list()`
- еще охапка дров и плов готов ;-)

Comment: Без тернарного if вряд ли обойдется

Comment: делал уже так оно запишет все значения в кавычки(

Comment: в какие кавычки? покажите свое решение тогда и результат который получается

Comment: @Алексей Р - `(a, b)[c in d]` - вот без всяких `if` :)))

Comment: @Zhihar 1. Да, 2. Но! Explicit is better than implicit

Comment: values = [21, 3, '43', 'pass', 'begin', 55, True, None] - изначальный список. Делаю так result = list(map(lambda x: str(x), values)) . Выходит так ['21', '3', '43', 'pass', 'begin', '55', 'True', 'None'].Может я неправильно вопрос задал , но после выполнения должно быть так чтобы только цифры на которых небыли кавычки изначально , после выполнения были в кавычках . Остальное без изменений (если слово без кавычек то в результате без), конкретно это немого сделать , не получается вернее.

Comment: я вам уже ответил в основном вопросе - ОПРЕДЕЛЯЙТЕ ТИП ДАННЫХ, и уже на основании типа делайте или е делайте преобразование в строку

Comment: result = list(map(lambda x: str(x) if type(int(x)) else: pass )) пробовал так , уже 3 часа сижу над этим ничего не получается

Comment: `type(x) is int` или `type(x)  == int`- это так работает, в гугле по запросу `python type` сразу бы нашли ответ, в тернарном операторе `else` идет без двоеточия, и должно быть так `если тип переменной равен int вернуть переменную, преобразованную в строку иначе вернуть исходную переменную`, поэтому вместо `pass` надо вернуть `x`: `str(x) if type(x) is int else x`

Comment: Спасибо буду дальше разбираться , с if else , тяжело даются он пока.